# Instalação Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk

Alguém poderia compartilhar algum manual de instalação e configuração do Eclipse atualizado, e que nesse manual possua os passos para a configuração das variáveis de ambiente para que eu possa compilar e executar os projetos?

Comment: Qual sistema operacional?

Comment: O sistema operacional que eu irei fazer uma nova instalação será Windows 10 32bits.

Comment: Configurar variáveis de ambiente java no windows: http://www.devmedia.com.br/preparacao-do-ambiente-para-desenvolvimento-em-java/25188 Rodar o Eclipse: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/civil-and-environmental-engineering/1-00-introduction-to-computers-and-engineering-problem-solving-spring-2012/tools/MIT1_00S12_Insl_Eclpse_Win.pdf

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar Emerson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A instalação no Windows é bem simples
Você está tentando configurar um projeto java? Se sim pode seguir este tutorial:

Resumo:

**Você vai precisar de:**

- JDK: Faça o download da versão mais atual aqui:

  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- Eclipse: Faça o download da versão mais atual aqui:

  http://eclipse.org/downloads/

**Instalando o JDK**

Execute o instalador do JDK e siga as instruções até concluir (next > next > finish), se desejar, é possível informar o diretório de instalação.

Juntamente com o JDK será feita a instalação do JRE (Java Runtime Environment) que é o aplicativo que permite executar os programas em JAVA no seu sistema operacional.

**Configurando o JAVA no Windows**

Clique com o botão direito em Computador e siga as opções Propriedades > Configurações avançadas do sistema > (aba Avançado) Variáveis de Ambiente…

Crie/edite as variáveis do sistema listadas abaixo:

- JAVA_HOME: informe o diretório da instalação do JDK. Exemplo
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45;
- Path: informe %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
- CLASSPATH: informe %JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;

Para confirmar que a instalação e configuração do JAVA foi realizada com sucesso, execute os comandos “java -version” e “javac -version” no prompt de comando.

**Instalando o Eclipse**

O Eclipse roda direto de um arquivo executável. Extraia o pacote “.zip” do Eclipse para o diretório de sua preferência. Execute o arquivo eclipse.exe para iniciar.

Ao iniciar o eclipse, você deve definir o workspace de trabalho (que é a pasta onde será mantido seu espaço de trabalho

Pronto! Seu JDK e Eclipse estão instalados e Configurados para programar em JAVA!

REF: http://www.matera.com/br/2015/05/12/tutorial-instalacao-do-java-jdk-e-eclipse-no-windows/

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar José!